# How to extract file name from AWS url?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the file name from URL and here I use basename to get the file name but it not works.

```
basename('https://test-assets.amazonaws.com/live%2Ftestsamantha-9-bucket%2Ff132eb33-f403-4881-80e2-de1cc3bdb43a.jpg');
```

Result is

```
live%2Ftestsamantha-9-bucket%2Ff132eb33-f403-4881-80e2-de1cc3bdb43a.jpg
```

How do I get

```
f132eb33-f403-4881-80e2-de1cc3bdb43a.jpg
```

Comment: what was your exact url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take the url just as you did, use [urldecode](https://php.net/urldecode) on it, so slashes are plain slashes and nothing encoded. Then all you have to do, is [explode](https://php.net/explode) by slash and take the last element of the created array. Voila.

```
$url = urldecode(basename('https://test-assets.amazonaws.com/live%2Ftestsamantha-9-bucket%2Ff132eb33-f403-4881-80e2-de1cc3bdb43a.jpg'));
$parts = explode('/', $url);

print end($parts); // Prints 'f132eb33-f403-4881-80e2-de1cc3bdb43a.jpg'
```

**Or better, do it like the other poster did, its less code and he is right. While my solution works too, its more than needed.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode the url first using the [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) method:

```
basename(urldecode('https://test-assets.amazonaws.com/live%2Ftestsamantha-9-bucket%2Ff132eb33-f403-4881-80e2-de1cc3bdb43a.jpg'));
```

The `urldecode` method converts the url to `https://test-assets.amazonaws.com/live/testsamantha-9-bucket/f132eb33-f403-4881-80e2-de1cc3bdb43a.jpg` and then the `basename` method works properly.

Comment: Take my upvote, you desever it more than me lmao